# External touchpad scroll speed

Tags: touchpad

I have bought a wireless keyboard with built-in touchpad (type Alcor W500-TP) to use with my Kubuntu 20.04 machine.
However, scrolling with two fingers is extremely slow.

All of the touchpad settings configure the built-in touchpad of my laptop (including the graphical KDE settings and `synclient` in terminal).

With `xinput --list-props "my-device-name"`, I see a bunch of settings, but none for scroll speed.

Do you know how could I fix it? Thanks!